# watchOS 2: background callbacks

Tags: background, watchos-2

I'm newbe to watch os 2, so don't really know where to start with this. 
Is it possible to write a WatchOs 2 app, that will run in background and will wake up once an hour?
There is not that much info available on the web, but what I've seen so far suggests that it's not possible to write background apps. Still, I'm wondering, how do you write an app that acts like an alarm clock and wakes up at specific times during the day?

Answer (score 1):

The simple WatchKit Apps can't run in background without user permission. In order to have you app running in the background, you must implement a Workout-style app, but instead of getting health and activity data, you can implement an alarm clock app, or something similar.

You can learn more on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) documentations by clicking on the link above.

Comment: This wouldn't actually work. Workout style apps can't just run code in the background.